# Raise the SMB session limit in Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, smb, session

Is it possibble to increase the number of allowed SMB sessions to more than 20 under Windows 7 Enterprise SP1?

Answer (score 1):

According to a [member of Microsoft Staff](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/thread/94eca5c3-2328-4b4d-a72f-537b8acfac7d), this is currently not possible. There may be a 3rd party unsupported patch, however.

Comment: +1 - Client editions of Windows have long been like this, to prevent people from using them as servers.  If you want lots of SMB (or IIS) sessions, go buy whatever edition of Windows server suits your needs, or switch the server to Linux/FreeBSD/other.